# Scroll down 100vh / Scroll down to next section. (Pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript, scroll

i'm working on a website where all my sections are 100vh. On scroll i want to go straight to the next section (so 100vh down). Is there a 'simple' way to do this with Javascript?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe using a plugin like https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/

Comment: You can do this without javascript, just with css, using scroll-snap-type and scroll-snap-align.

Answer (score 0):

try this code or check live demo at https://codepen.io/libin-prasanth/pen/yLLqoyQ

Once mouse scrolled it will move to next section and mouse event stop work for 3 section, if you don't need this event hide this from Javascript

```js
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
  document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
} else {
  document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
}

var i = 1;
var mouseWheel = true;
function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
  if(!mouseWheel){
    return false;
  }
  mouseWheel = false;
  setTimeout(function(){
    mouseWheel = true;
  }, 3000); // Stop mouse wheel event for 3 seconds 
  e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, e.wheelDelta || -e.detail));
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var section = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
  if (i <= section.length && i >= 0) {
    //scrolling down?
    if (delta < 0) { 
      window.scrollTo({
        top: h * i,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
   i++; 
    } else {
      //scrolling up?
      window.scrollTo({
        top: h * i,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
      i--;
    }
  } else {
   i = 1;
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section{
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ff9800;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">Some section 1</div>
<div class="section" style="background: #ff5722">Some section 2</div>
<div class="section " style="background: #000">Some section 3</div>
<div class="section" style="background: #fff">Some section 4 </div>
<div class="section " style="background: #ccc">Some section 5</div>
<div class="section" style="background: #f00">Some section 6</div>
<div class="section " style="background: blue">Some section 6</div>
<div class="section" style="background: #DDD">Some section 7</div>
```

Comment: Hi Libin, thank you very much for the code but it isn't working smooth. Also it doesn't really listen to where you want to scroll.. Thank you tho

Comment: Do you think i can change the delay? So that i can scroll without having to wait for it to snap to the next section?

Comment: let's find setTimeout function and replace 3000 with 0

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://24ways.org/2019/beautiful-scrolling-experiences-without-libraries/) are much simpler solutions working with these simple css tags:

> 

```
 .scroll-container {
       overflow-x: scroll;
       scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
     }

   .section {
       height: 100%;
       flex: 0 0 100%;
       scroll-snap-align: center;
     }
```